# How to copy text from tooltip in Html/JS

Tags: javascript, java, html, tooltip

I have an image on a page. On hovering to the image, you see a tool tip with some details. Say, for example - `Name : xyz, Account id : abc1234, Technical id : 0000`

User wants to copy some text from this tooltip like the account id `abc1234`. How can this be achieved in JS?

I am asking this from code perspective so that the end user can use this functionality. I am not looking for any hacks/tricks to copy the text from browser.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS.

You can set a hover style in css, and set a hover class, with absolute positioning (top, left, right, bottom) and create a div:after and set the content with [attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).

That means you need to write the values into attributes on the image.

```
.tooltip:hover:after
{
    border: 1px solid #fc0;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    background: #fffea1;
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    # right: 0px;
    # bottom: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

To concatenate two or more string values in CSS, separate them with whitespace:

```
.tooltip:hover:after
{
    content: attr(class) ' ' attr(data-size);
}
```

Note that the whitespace between the attr() functions and the quotes is not the same as the whitespace within the quotes. The latter is an actual string containing a space character, which will separate the two attribute values in the output. The whitespace between the three parts is the operator that joins them together.

Unfortunately, most browsers do not support using :after or :before on img tags, so you need to change your img to a div with background-image:

```
<div style="position:relative; display: inline-block; background-color: green;">

<div style="display:block; width: 32px; height: 32px; 
  background-size: 32px 32px;
background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaCKR.jpg');" class="tooltip" data-title="I am the basic tooltip content"></div>


</div>
```

Another unfortunate circumstance is, that you can't copy from pseudo-elements...

So, if you want to do it in JavaScript, the mouse events are mouseover/mouseout or mouseenter/mouseleave. Something along the lines of:

```
function attachHoverHandler()
{
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var text = document.createTextNode('Before - ');
  var div = document.createElement("div")
  div.appendChild(text);


  fragment.appendChild(div);



  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), function (img) {
      console.log("adding", img);
      // img.insertBefore(fragment.cloneNode(), img.parentElement.firstChild);
      img.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event){ 
        /* here goes your code */ 
        img.parentElement.insertBefore(fragment.cloneNode(true), img);
        console.log("mouseenter", event);
      });

      img.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event){ 
        /* here goes your code */ 
        img.parentElement.removeChild(img.previousSibling);
        console.log("mouseleave", event);
      });
  });
}


function autorun()
{
  console.clear();
  attachHoverHandler();
}


   // event listener
   if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", autorun, false);
   else if (document.attachEvent) document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", autorun);
   else window.onload = autorun;
```